# Display the number of selected column for batch actions with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Hi I am developing admin page with [**Active Admin**](https://activeadmin.info/).

I made a batch action and now I try to show the number of 'selected' column. but I cannot find the way.

This is the batch actions what I wanted ([by NG-admin](https://marmelab.com/images/blog/ng-admin/ng-admin-batch-actions.gif)).

Can I make **'3 Batch Actions'** instead of just **'Batch Actions'**? Or can I display the number of selected column in different way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

oh I use this.

```
// app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.collection_selection').on("click", countChecked);
  $('input.toggle_all').on("click", countChecked);
});

let countChecked = function() {
  let menuButton = $('a.dropdown_menu_button');
  setTimeout(function() {
    let count = $('input.collection_selection:checked').length;
    menuButton.find("span").remove();
    if (count > 0) { menuButton.append("<span> (" + count + ")</span>"); }
  });
}
```